# PHP: Как обработать фатальную ошибку в методе класса и вернуть управление вызывающему коду?

Tags: php, исключения, php7, обработка-ошибок

Изучая PHP (7.3.9 TS), натолкнулся на очень непонятную мне модель обработки ошибок и исключений. Прочитал много статей на эту тему и, разумеется, [документацию по PHP](https://www.php.net/). Увы, ясности так и не прибавилось.

Не могу понять как сделать так, чтобы при возникновении исключения/ошибки/фатальной ошибки в методе класса я мог бы 1) обрабатывать её сам; 2) вернуть управление вызывающему коду (функции).

Простейший пример:

```
namespace MyNamespace;

class MyClass
{
  public function dl_file($url) {
    $stream = file_get_contents($url);
  }
}
```

Вызываю этот метод из `test.php` вот таким образом:

```
$f = 'http://www.mysite.com/images/non-existent-image.jpg';

$mc = new MyNamespace\MyClass();

print_r($mc->dl_file($f));
```

В публичном методе класса я делаю попытку загрузить изображение. В том случае, если файл отсутствует, я получаю информацию о фатальной ошибке

> Warning: file_get_contents(1500): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\myclass.php on line 68

Я хочу чтобы это сообщение НЕ появлялось ни при каких обстоятельствах. Но что бы я ни делал, какими бы конструкциями не "обматывал" бы потенциально опасный вызов, я не могу добиться того, что это сообщение исчезнет. Я пробовал и `try...throw...catch` и использовал различные классы в обработчике, например `Exception $e`, `Throwable $e` и `Error $e` (как советуется [вот в этой статье](https://netgen.io/blog/modern-error-handling-in-php) *(англ.)*).

Но, к сожалению, сообщение о фатальной ошибке появляется всегда и означает, что PHP-core попросту игнорирует мои стремления получить контроль над скриптом после возникновения фатальной ошибки.

В идеале мне хотелось бы просто сгенерировать собственное сообщение об ошибке и вернуть его caller-у в виде массива. Например, как-то так:

```
public function dl_file($url) {
  
  try {
    $stream = file_get_contents($url);
  }
  
  catch (\ВсеЧтоМнеПоможет $e) {
    return array(
      'err_id'  => $e->code;
      'err_msg' => $e->message;
    )
  }

}
```

То есть *мне нужно проигнорировать фатальную ошибку*, перехватив контроль над её обработкой, а затем вернуть управление вызывающему коду из `test.php`.

Имеет ли смысл прикручивать сюда [пользовательский обработчик ошибок](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.set-error-handler.php) для меня так же непонятно, потому что мне важно не сколько обработать ошибку, сколько вернуть управление вызывающей функции.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: "НЕ появлялось ни при каких обстоятельствах" - где не появлялось?

Comment: В браузере. (а где же еще?) То есть когда я ввожу в строку браузера `https://www.mysite.com/test.php` это сообщение появляется в результате возникновения фатальной ошибке в коде.

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', 0);` - вопрос решён

Comment: Но ошибка-то все равно произойдет, прячь-не прячь сообщение о ней.

Comment: @Ипатьев, это сомнительное предложение. Если вы внимательно прочитали мой вопрос.

Comment: Я внимательно прочитал его и уже написал примерно половину ответа. И напишу вторую, если меня не отвлекать.

Comment: @u_mulder, именно поэтому мне нужно вернуть управление в вызывающий код (где я смогу, например, ошибку полностью проигнорировать, повторить вызов и т.д.)

Comment: Смотрите в сторону написания собственной функции-обработчика ошибок.

Comment: ошибка на то фатальна, что нарушает работу системы, а раз ругается на нее, значит интерпретатор на нее уже наступил. Возвращать некуда, коллеги правы

Answer (score 2):

Весь вопрос - одна сплошная путаница в понятиях и практически целиком основан на неверных предпосылках. Поэтому для начала ответим на тот вопрос, который буквально сформулирован в заголовке, тем более что ответ простой и незамысловатый

> Как обработать фатальную ошибку и вернуть управление

**Никак**
На то она и фатальная. [Поймать можно, но возвращать уже **некуда**](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting#fatal). Максимум, что можно сделать - это показать какой-нибудь кастомный НТТР код клиенту, ну и залогировать.

Другое дело, что *банальный warning* никаким местом фатальной ошибкой не является.

Не говоря уже о том, что file_get_contents кидающий варнинг при НТТР запросе - это банальная неграмотность и ничего более.

Чтобы ловить ошибки через try, надо их превращать в исключения. В этом таки поможет [пользовательский обработчик ошибок](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting#converting_errors_to_exceptions).

***Но!** Хотя сама по себе практика конвертации ошибок в исключения является правильной и должна всячески пропагандироваться, **злоупотреблять при этому ловлей ошибок через try не стоит**. Ошибки бывают РАЗНЫЕ. Какую-то ты хочешь поймать и отправить дальше, а какую-то лучше оставить в покое и не трогать. И грести все под одну гребенку нельзя.*

В данном случае, если в catch планируется анализ конкретной ошибки и реакция только в случае если ошибка именно та, которую мы ожидаем, то использование try..catch оправдано. Если ошибка оказалась не та - надо её *перевыбросить*, `throw $e` и дать кому-то другому её обработать.

Но если брать конкретный пример с file_get_contents(), то - как уже говорилось выше - такой варнинг это чистой воды головотяпство. С НТТР надо работать предназначенными для этого инструментами. Т.е. либо через CURL, либо перед вызовом file_get_contents() задавать контекст с [нужными параметрами](https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php#context.http.timeout).

В сухом остатке

- чтобы ловить обычные ошибки, их надо конвертировать в исключения через кастомный обработчик
- фатальную ошибку сконвертировать нельзя
- чтобы file_get_contents не выдавала ошибок, её надо правильно готовить
- чтобы сообщения об ошибках не выводились браузер, надо просто сообщить РНР об этом - `ini_set('display_errors', 0);`

Comment: глубокая фраза у Вас в профиле, надо взять на вооружение.